# Generalized sum-function

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and looking for a smart way to reduce redundancy in my code.

```
 public double sumx()
    {
        double temp = 0;
        foreach (var item in col)
        {
            temp= temp + item.x;
        }
        return temp;
    }
    public double sumy()
    {
        double temp = 0;
        foreach (var item in col)
        {
            temp = temp + item.y;
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

*col* is of type *List< Point >* and *Point* is a class by my own, which provides two properties (*x and y*) and an constructor *Point(x,y)*.

I want now the sum of all x, respectively sum of all y.

I'm looking for a more generalized *sum* function, which maybe uses *delegates* or *Lambda* expressions. I have no Idea how to do this in a smart c# way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out [`Enumerable.Sum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, use the `Sum` extension method from Linq:

```
public double sumx()
{
    return col.Sum(item => item.x);
}
public double sumy()
{
    return col.Sum(item => item.y);
}
```

Comment: Well, at this point making a function for this has no great value.

Comment: @Steve other than shortening the call and saving the caller from writing a lambda, but yes, it's not a huge gain.  Also would be required if `x` or `y` were private.

Comment: I am just suggesting that this could remove at all the need of a specific method and probably gives a better clue to what's happening. But I am digressing. Your answer is absolutely correct.

Comment: Thanks D Stanley and Steve, that's the c# way I was looking for. I just need the results of the two functions for another function which calculcates regression coefficients. But the Linq way is so short (as mentioned by Steve), that I will use it directly in the function which calculates the regression coefficients. So I can remove sum x/y.